# multiple errors when attempting to make user form input to excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a userform with checkboxes, combo boxes text input into the cells of the next row of the excel sheet. I've tried so many ways to make it work but it won't input:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rowcount As Long
Dim ws As worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Raw Data")
rowcount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row

With ws
.Cells(rowcount, 0).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 1).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 2).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 3).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 4).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 5).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 6).Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 7).Value = Me.TextBox8.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 8).Value = Me.TextBox9.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 9).Value = Me.TextBox10.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 10).Value = Me.PNBox.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 11).Value = Me.ENBox.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 12).Value = Me.CheckBox4.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 13).Value = Me.CheckBox5.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 14).Value = Me.CheckBox6.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 15).Value = Me.CheckBox7.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 19).Value = Me.CheckBox11.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 20).Value = Me.CheckBox12.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 21).Value = Me.CheckBox13.Value
.Cells(rowcount, 22).Value = Me.CheckBox14.Value
```

I want to make each variable show up on the next column on the sheet and blanks or false items to stay blank.

Comment: You can't have column zero `.Cells(rowcount, 0)`.

Comment: Btw "it won't input" is not a terribly helpful way of describing your problem.